# Declaration of CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_escape_str($str) should be compatible with CI_DB_driver::_escape_str($str, $like = false)

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I'm having a hard time with this kind of error, and this is my code.

Here's for the Database Configuration:

```
 $db['default'] = array(
   'dsn'    => '',
   'hostname' => 'localhost',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'database' => 'nipadb',
   'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => TRUE,
   'db_debug' => TRUE,
   'cache_on' => FALSE,
   'cachedir' => '',
   'char_set' => 'utf8',
   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   'swap_pre' => '',
   'encrypt' => FALSE,
   'compress' => FALSE,
   'stricton' => FALSE,
   'failover' => array(),
   'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Here's my Controller Main:

```
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('hotel_model');
 }

public function home(){
    $this->load->view("template/header_page");
    $this->load->view("carousel");
    $this->load->view("template/footer_page");
}

public function signUp(){
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastnameGuest','Last Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstnameGuest','First Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailGuest','Email','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('genderGuest','Gender','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobileGuest','Mobile Number','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('usernameGuest','Username','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordGuest','Password','trim|required|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('conpasswordGuest', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[passwordGuest]|md5');



    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view("template/header_page");
        $this->load->view("context/signUp");
        $this->load->view("template/footer_page");
    }else{
       // $this->hotel_model->registerGuest();

        $data = array(
            'FirstName' => $this->input->post('firstnameGuest'),
            'LastName' => $this->input->post('lastnameGuest'),
            'Gender' => $this->input->post('genderGuest'),
            'MobileNumber' => $this->input->post('mobileGuest'),
            'EmailAddress' => $this->input->post('emailGuest'),
            'Username' => $this->input->post('usernameGuest'),
            'Password' => md5($this->input->post('usernameGuest'))
        );

        $this->hotel_model->registerGuest($data);

        $this->session->set_userdata('signUp-success',"You will be Logged in ");
        $this->load->view("template/header_page");
        $this->load->view("context/signUp-success",$data);
        $this->load->view("template/footer_page");
    }
}
```

And here's Model for `hotel_model`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

//register guest
public function registerGuest($data){
    $this->db->insert('guest',$data);
}

public function logIn(){
    $this->load->library('session');

    $loginSQL = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE (Username = '" .       mysqli_real_escape_string($this->input->post('username')) . "') and (Password = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string(md5($this->input->post('password'))) . "')");

    return $loginSQL;
}
```

This the usual error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Declaration of CI_DB_mysqli_driver::_escape_str($str) should be compatible with CI_DB_driver::_escape_str($str, $like = false)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 544
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_SOFT_ENG\application\models\hotel_model.php
> Line: 12
> Function: database
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_SOFT_ENG\application\controllers\Main.php
> Line: 16
> Function: model
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_SOFT_ENG\index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Comment: Rather than showing all your code, trying winnowing it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry I'm actually kinda new to this thing...

Comment: @ElijahPamintuan You'll get used to it. Just try and figure out what the essence of your problem is, and post exclusively this. While people here are willing to help you, they probably don't want to read a long bunch of code that is potentially not related to the core of the problem.

Comment: When in doubt - read the user guide... It has lots of goodies... https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html?highlight=escape#escaping-queries

Answer (score 0):

CI has built in character escape function
try this `$this->db->escape()` instead